# how to get mssql_connect to work on windows 7

Tags: php, sql-server

I have mssql_* functions working on my Ubuntu installation and want to duplicate this on my windows 7 box.  I have installed wamp on the win7 box, but I cannot get it to see the mssql_* functions.  I have read many posts about nothing is working.  I have the ext directory properly set.  I have extension=php_mssql.dll  do not see the mssql section in phpinfo, but I do see sqlsrv section.   I would like my prod and test environment to match.

Thanks in advance for any assistance
Dean-O

Comment: This is the right time to switch to PDO... :)

Comment: @ZombieHunter - Not really. There's no stable PDO driver for SQL Server under non-Windows platforms.

Comment: It's also not really ideal to put php my a windows; and, well I've had nothing but problems with wamp/xampp php aside. IIS is the only server I've gotten to work on windows, and it's not exactly php-friendly either. Your production environment is ubuntu?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ??? PDO has come bundled with PHP on any OS for years!

Comment: @Assimilater - Well, I guess that, in theory, you could use [PDO_DBLIB](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) under Linux and [PDO_SQLSRV](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) under Windows. After all, the API is supposed to be the same. Not sure if you meant that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario my bad. just noticed this has the tag sql-server, but I thought they were asking about mysql. sql-server is available on linux? Odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked my local wampserver 2.1 installation, and although there's an option to enable the php_mssql extension, it's missing from the extensions directory.

You can try the FreeTDS extension, which supposedly works fine under both *nix and Windows.

The Moodle wiki specifies that the Microsoft SQL Server driver has "known problems":

> WARNING: This driver has known problems and is therefore not suitable
>   for any Moodle production servers.

and recommends the use of FreeTDS instead (by installing the php_dblib extension). Moodle is a known user of MSSQL, and a respected project, but they don't really specify what they mean by "known problems", so you can take this with a grain of salt...

http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

If FreeTDS doesn't work for you, you can try installing the official Microsoft drivers:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: The Microsoft drivers do not work on wamp.  I will try the moodle ones